# Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.FormattingUtilities'

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android

On a PCL project for a Xamarin.Android project, I'm getting the following error when I do a `httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync()` or a `httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync()`.

Error:

`System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.FormattingUtilities' from assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.`

This error occurs in this code:

```
public async Task<User> CreateUser(string name, string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.Name = name;
            user.Email = email;
            user.Password = password;

            var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("myUrl", user); // error on this line
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(content) ? new User() :
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(content);
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex; // ex is null here
        }
}
```

Comment: try deleting all files under package and bin and obj folders under your web.ui proj (or other names, just the frontend project)

Comment: or adding assembly dependencies config in <assemblyBinding/> like <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: @NathanGong, nope, it did not worked.

Comment: What about deleting and installing it again using nuget?

Comment: @NathanGong, yes, but it did not worked. I added the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension` nuget package. Is this the right one? Or should I add the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`?

Comment: This was the first of several errors I got, culminating with [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100) that turned out to be the root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give up.

I changed it to:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await _client.PostAsync(myUrl, stringContent);
```

Now it works.